# How can I know whether or not I should use the bare infinitive after a verb?

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives

I usually make the mistake

'I **prefer watch** movies' instead of 'I **prefer to watch** movies'

Is there a grammar rule that can help me to remember not to make this mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["prefer ~ing" / "prefer to infinitive"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63348/prefer-ing-prefer-to-infinitive)

Comment: Is not a duplicate because he didn't make my mistake "I prefer watch movies". He is asking about the 2 correct forms.

Comment: Carlos - there's not really a "rule" saying whether you should say *I prefer **to watch*** or *I prefer **watching***. They're both fine, and they mean the same thing. The first (infinitive) is still slightly more common, but the second (gerund) is becoming more popular with each passing decade, so it'll probably be the most common form eventually. Your first one *(I prefer watch)* with a "bare infinitive" is completely ungrammatical, and I see no benefit in exploring it any further.

Comment: Where did you find "I prefer watch movies" in actual usage?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the question for clearness.

Comment: Carlos - the reason you can't use the bare infinitive ***watch*** in your example is because that's only valid after a [***modal***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb) verb. For example, *I **can** watch, I **must** watch, I **used to** watch*. It's not valid for normal verbs such as *I **like** watch* (which is ungrammatical).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that is actually a good answer to this question.

Comment: @ColleenV: OP has amended the question since I cast my dup closevote. But even if I could still vote, I'd closevote for lack of prior research now we can see exactly what's troubling OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure it's so simple to do that research if you don't know that the difference is modal verbs. I know which verbs I should and shouldn't use the bare infinitive with and from there I can figure out what the difference is, but if you aren't fluent, how do you figure that out? If the question is answerable and on-topic I think a down-vote is more appropriate than a close-vote, but that's a recent shift in my thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a verb as a noun most of the time it needs the word *to* in front of it or *-ing* tacked on the end of it.

> I prefer *to watch* movies
>
> I prefer *watching* movies

Certain verbs used in certain ways, if followed by an infinitive, require or encourage that the *to* not be present.  This is called a *bare infinitive*. *Prefer* is not one of these.

Some useful heuristics for deciding when to omit the *to*:

- They [bare infinitives] usually occur after certain verbs like feel, hear, help, let, make, see, and watch.  [[reference](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/infinitive.html)]
- In the construction *X to do { form of to be } Y*, where Y is an infinitive, *to* is usually omitted.

> All I want to do is walk.

Comment: But it's not ungrammatical to include the 'to' in your last example, correct? 'All I want to do is to walk, to smoke, and to ponder my existence.' (just clarifying, not criticizing)

Comment: Right, you can still include the *to* for the last example.