# Using a verb after a verb

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm always confused in using a verb after a verb.

For example:

- I prefer **using** the computer.
- I prefer **to use** the computer.
- I like **to help** people.
- I like **helping** people.
- ... etc.

Actually the verb+ing is not verb, but I cannot decide when to use "to".

Comment: You can look up verbs that "take" ing. https://avi.cuaieed.unam.mx/uapa/avi/ing_3/U_3/ing3_u3_t2/index.html Some take either to or ing, some don't.

Comment: The catenative verbs "prefer" and "like" both take either a _to_- infinitival clause as complement or a gerund-participial one.

Comment: According to the link Lambie shared, it depends on the verb you use. As far as I understand, I need to memorize them. I've not heard this word "catenative" before. Thank you @BillJ

Comment: I only mentioned the verbs "prefer" and "like" because they were the ones you used in your examples. Other verbs differ. Catenative verbs are those that take another non-finite  verb as complement, as in your examples. This link gives a list of which verbs take which complements: [list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prefer doing vs prefer to do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192806/prefer-doing-vs-prefer-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

> [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) *I prefer* [*using the computer*].
>
> [2] *I prefer* [*to use the computer*].
>
> [3] *I like* [*to help people*].
>
> [4] *I like* [*helping people*].

"Prefer" and "like" take either *to*-infinitival or gerund-participial clauses as complement.

Clauses like these whose verbs have an immediate  non-finite clause as their complement (so they form a 'chain'), are called catenative constructions.

[Some verbs take infinitivals, some take gerund-participials (_ing forms), and others](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs) take past-particpials. And some verbs can take more than one type.